# regular expression to validate 2 alphanumerics

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have the follow pattern to validate a string, it has to validate **4 letters**, **6 numbers**, **6 letters** and **2 alphanumerics**, but with my current pattern I cant get a valid test

```
Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{4}\\d{6}\\w{6}\\[A-ZÑa-zñ0-9\\- ]{2}");
```

I think my pattern it's wrong, because I'm not shure about this `[A-ZÑa-zñ0-9\\- ]{2}`

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$
```

Check it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/PKifUc/1).
In your expression you are using `\w+`, which does not only match digits and alphabetic characters, but also underscores `_`.

Comment: For international support: `^\\p{L}{4}\\p{Nd}{6}\\p{L}{6}[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]{2}$` or maybe: `(?U)^\\p{Alpha}{4}\\p{Digit}{6}\\p{Alpha}{6}\\p{Alnum}{2}$`

Answer (score 1):

A few things off on your regex.

- You have extra backslashes in your digit and word matching. Change from `\\d` to `\d` and `\\w` to `\w`.
- The `\\` is not needed.
- Your end regex is invalid syntax. Just remove the `"\\- "` bit.

You can also slim down your initial part to be `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z]`. So, you're new regex should look like:

```
"\w{4}\d{6}\w{6}[A-ZÑa-zñ0-9]{2}"
```

That is if you're okay with the only non-ascii characters being Ñ and ñ in your last two alphanumerics.